# AOF rewrites happening before the file size reaches 100%

Tags: database, memory, redis, persistence

AOF file rewrites are getting triggered before reaching the file size limit of 100%. My config:

```
auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 100
auto-aof-rewrite-min-size 64mb
aof_last_cow_size:504176640
aof_current_size:5770369649
aof_base_size:5486679840
```

As per my understanding, it should reach both conditions(auto-aof-rewrite-percentage and auto-aof-rewrite-min-size) to trigger the AOF rewrite. AOF file size is 5GB and I was expecting the next AOF rewrite to trigger when file size is 10GB, however it does 3-4 times a day.

Comment: Check if some one run a BGSAVE or BGREWRITEAOF command manually.

Comment: yep, i did check to see any manual commands but they are not run manually.

Comment: I am monitoring the size of the disk changing over the time along with the AOF sizes to see if the change i find anything out of normal..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info commandstats does not have any indication of BGREWRITEAOF being executed manually.. However after comparing the disk/aof file size during these times and the aof_rewrite_time_sec guage.. i do see that aof size is elastic in nature trigerring the rewrites.. based on a given point in a day.. the size of the aof is getting changed(optimized)..( 3-7GiB) that may be because of the number of entries and also with the ttl's that are configured for the key.. i am investigating further.. so far i see that this is a valid trigger happening due to the file size increase..

Thank you for your time...